# Output map of only 50m-100m contours

Tags: qgis, contour, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

I´ve got the "OS Terrain 50" contours/spot-heights dataset. 
I would like to output a series of maps with everything above 0m, 50m, 100m etc. from a region.
I know almost nothing about GIS, but have a reasonable technical knowledge.

There are lots of GIS programs, but which would be best/easiest to do this in.

Thanks

Edit: Limited (tagged) the program to the recommended QGIS.
I am wanting to make a physical model of some land. Terrain outline at different heights above sea level will give some templates to cut out and stack to make an actual model. Hope it´s not going too far off topic.

Comment: http://qgis.org/en/site/ is free and it quite a powerful open source GIS.

Comment: There's two questions here. For the second question: QGIS is one of the best GIS packages for free and there's lots of help for the beginner. ESRI is king of the GIS world but it costs - **a lot** not only the software but there are educational products. For the first question: it depends on what software you use, but doesn't sound difficult. I would just do a definition query for each elevation band, how to implement that is software dependent but here's how to do it in QGIS https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to focus it on the GIS product you are most likely to use, please?  Otherwise I think it is too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson -- seems like an answer to me

Comment: Not sure i understand quite what "everything above 0m, 50m, 100m etc. from a region" means. Why would you wish to exclude anything below 0m, 50m, 100m etc on a map?

Comment: @PolyGeo -- But the OP doesn't know which GIS to use. The Q should perhaps expand more on the requirements of and other constraints upon the intended use of a GIS.

Comment: @martinf I think the asker needs to research GIS products of interest to him/her and then ask how to "output a series of maps with everything above 0m, 50m, 100m etc. from a region" using the one he/she likes the look of first.  If the Answer(s) to that are not appealing then he/she is in a position to research/ask about how to do it using his/her second choice.

Answer (score 1):

Fabula, there is two questions asked here in one. The rules for the site is one question per question, may I suggest that you take the [two minute tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) otherwise you might get some less than helpful responses in the future.

Now that that's been addressed..

For the second question: what software? QGIS is one of the best GIS packages for free and there's lots of help for the beginner, I've not created a hard-copy map from it but I've heard it isn't too bad. ESRI is king of the GIS world but it costs - **a lot**, not only the software but there are educational products ranging from on line to instructor lead.

For the first question: It depends on what software you use, but doesn't sound difficult. I would just do a [definition query](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/definition%20query) for each elevation band, how to implement that is software dependent but here's how to [do it in QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html). It is a fairly basic GIS capability and should be common among software packages... here's how to [do it in ESRI](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000).

Please note if these links become broken, as they do over time, google  definition query and you'll find your answer on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS, load the contour shapefile, right-click on it in the layers panel and go down to 'Filter...'. Under 'Provider specific filter expression' type:

```
"PROP_VALUE" IN (0,50,100,150)
```

exactly as shown, then press OK.

This will display the contours having values of 0, 50, 100, and 150 metres. You can add values to the expression if required.

I'm not quite sure where you want to go after this, but it should get you started.

N.